# Pushing multidimensional arrays as keys on another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an empty array (as an example) and a number of multidimensional arrays I would like to push onto this array. However I would like the keys of each multidimensional array to become a key of the empty array

Using

```
$myEmptyArray[] = $arrayOne;
$myEmptyArray[] = $arrayTwo;
$myEmptyArray[] = $arrayThree;
```

I get

```
[
    0 => ['one' => ['a' => 'stuff']],
    1 => ['two' => ['b' => 'stuff']],
    2 => ['three' => ['c' => 'stuff']]
]
```

I would prefer to have

```
[
    'one' => ['a' => 'stuff'],
    'two' => ['b' => 'stuff'],
    'three' => ['c' => 'stuff']
]
```

What is a neat and compact way (one liner or native php function) to do this without having to read the array key with a foreach and then assign this key explicitly to the empty array with the value like

```
foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $value) {
    $myEmptyArray[$key] = $value
}
```

As I will want to use this in many places in my code

Comment: Wouldn't `array_merge` do the job? Or out your foreach loop in a function with variable parameters count and use it whenever you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`+` (union)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) operator which "returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored".

```
$array = [];
$array += ['one' => ['a' => 'stuff']];
$array += ['two' => ['b' => 'stuff']];
$array += ['three' => ['b' => 'stuff']];
var_dump($array);
/*
array(3) {
  'one' =>
  array(1) {
    'a' =>
    string(5) "stuff"
  }
  'two' =>
  array(1) {
    'b' =>
    string(5) "stuff"
  }
  'three' =>
  array(1) {
    'b' =>
    string(5) "stuff"
  }
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `+` to combine those array in the way you want:

```
$arrayOne = array('one' => array('a' => 'stuff'));
$arrayTwo = array('two' => array('b' => 'stuff'));
$arrayThree = array('three' => array('c' => 'stuff'));

$myEmptyArray = array();
$myEmptyArray += $arrayOne;
$myEmptyArray += $arrayTwo;
$myEmptyArray += $arrayThree;

echo "<pre>"; print_r($myEmptyArray); echo "</pre>";
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [a] => stuff
        )

    [two] => Array
        (
            [b] => stuff
        )

    [three] => Array
        (
            [c] => stuff
        )

)
```